# shallow copying an array of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I have an array with child arrays. I'd want to shift the first element in the first child array
(`arr[0].shift`). But my code below shifts **all** first elements for **all** child arrays.

I figure it has something to do with *fillWith* being a deep-copy, but I've tried in every way I know to make it a shallow copy instead..

What am I missing?

```
let arr= Array(3)        
let fillWith = Array.from({length: 5}, (_, i) => i+1);

arr.fill([...[], ...fillWith]) // Try 1
//arr.fill(fillWith.slice()) // Try 2


console.log(arr) // -> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

arr[0].shift();

console.log(arr)
/* 
How I want it to be -> [[2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
What it actually becomes -> [[2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
*/
```

Comment: You filled `arr` with 3 references to the same array `fillWith`. This is how `fill` works.

Comment: By the way, `[...[], ...x]` is overkill for making a shallow copy of `x`.   Actually, `[...x]` accomplishes the same.  But of course, your problem was calling `fill` (You should have reached for `Array.from` again.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do it like this:

```js
const fillWith = () => Array.from({length: 5}, (_, i) => i + 1);

const arr = Array.from({length: 3}, fillWith)

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))

arr[0].shift();

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I will try it! Do you know why it works and mine doesn't?
Des functions always return a shallow copy?

Comment: @Soerman, `fill` first evaluates the expression within parenthesis, then fills the array with the result. In your case, it's a reference to the same array `fillWith`. I'm using a function that creates a new array each time, thus the returning references refer to different arrays.

Comment: Or as a one-liner:  `const arr = Array.from({length: 3}, () => Array.from({length:5}, (_,i) => i+1))`

Comment: @Wyck, yes, let's burn their brain.

Comment: Okey that makes sense! So even if I made the array within the paranthesis a shallow copy at first, that copy itself will be deeply copied for every filling, right?

Yea one-liner is nice!

You almost sound condescending when you write "their brain" 

Comment: @Soerman, you're right, every filling will be a reference to the same result of the expression within the parenthesis as it evaluates once, then it's being used. Regarding "their brain", I mean it's less readable, IMHO.